# How to load related objects efficiently in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join, design-patterns

## The situation

I'm using PHP & PDO with mysql and would like to query 1 table as well as rows that it points to in another table.

I have a class like:

```php
class Pet {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $owner;
}
```

and a table

```
pet
id | name | type | owner_id
0  | jim  | cat  | 87
1  | gale | dog  | 50
2  | foxy | cat  | 60
```

You can see that `Pet` refers to an Owner. This class is like:

```php
class Person {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $pets;
}
```

And the table

```
person
id | name 
87 | Joshua
50 | Bob
60 | Cynthia
```

Now, I want to get all the cats, with each property set, including the owner.

---

## Solution 1

If i have a query like:

```sql
SELECT pet.*, person.* FROM pet
JOIN person
    ON person.id = pet.ownerId
WHERE pet.type LIKE 'cat'
```

With the associative array returned, this will create a conflict on both `id` and `name` columns.

I have two options
1.) Use the numeric indices returned to map to the `Pet` objects and related `Person` objects
2.) prefix table column names & use the associative array returned to instantiate the objects

---

## Solution 2

Or I can do a query like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE pet.type LIKE 'cat'
```

and get a resulting associative array. I can loop over and get a list of all the owner ids and do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM person WHERE person.id IN (LIST_OF_IDS)
```

then instantiate the `Person` objects and assign them to the `$owner` property of my `Pet` objects.

---

## complaints

### Solution 1.1 (numeric indices)

This will technically work, but then I have to map numeric entries to the correct property names, which seems very prone to error, especially with any changes to DB schema.

### Solution 1.2 (prefixes)

This will work pretty easily, but upon reading up, prefixing column names is discouraged. Also... I don't really want to prefix my column names.

### Solution 2

This will work, but does not seem performant.

## Question

Are there other options for this that I'm missing?

I tried figuring out a way to prefix the column name in the `SELECT` statement (which would be fine, as it wouldn't affect the actual database), but it does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't change or prefix **all** column names (`person.* as person.*`) at once in MySQL, only single columns as mentioned in other answers. Since you've mentioned using the PDO as well, consider other approaches, two of them below.

**1.3: Use PDO statement [getColumnMeta()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)**

This will ask the database additional metadata about the numeric column:

```php
$qry = "SELECT pet.*, person.* FROM pet JOIN person ON person.id = pet.owner_id WHERE pet.type LIKE 'cat'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute();       
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $meta = $stmt->getColumnMeta($key);
        echo $meta['table'] . '.' . $meta['name'] . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

/* Output: 
pet.id: 2
pet.name: foxy
pet.type: cat
pet.owner_id: 60
person.id: 60
person.name: Bob
..
*/
```

**1.4: Use PDO statement fetch with fetch_style [PDO::FETCH_NAMED](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)**

This will make fields that have the same name become an array. Still be aware of the ordering: `SELECT pet.*, person.*` vs. `SELECT person.*, pet.*`.

```php
$qry = "SELECT pet.*, person.* FROM pet JOIN person ON person.id = pet.owner_id WHERE pet.type LIKE 'cat'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute();       
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED)) {
    echo $row['name'][1] . ' owns a ' . $row['type'] . ' named ' . $row['name'][0] . PHP_EOL;
}

/* Output:
Bob owns a cat named foxy
Joshua owns a cat named jim
*/
```

Comment: Thanks. I came accross `getColumnMeta` but guess I didn't look at it long enough. Hadn't noticed `PDO::FETCH_NAMED`. I think I'll write a little function with `getColumnMeta` to split results by table name and then go that route.

Comment: Good luck with it! :) Perhaps [this user note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php#88432) might come in useful for it.

Comment: Nice answer! I had completely forgotten about FETCH_NAMED

Answer (score 2):

You can alias the columns in one or both of the tables so they won't be ambiguous, for example:

```
SELECT pet.*, person.name AS owner_name
FROM pet JOIN person ON person.id = pet.ownerId
WHERE pet.type LIKE 'cat'
```

(You don't need to select the id from the person table since it will already be included as ownerId.)

Comment: Yeah, that's a... very valid option. I was hoping not to alias all my columns... nor explicitly name them. Though, I've also read that `table.*` is bad practice, so I guess I should get over it (and be explicit & alias)? lol

Comment: IMO using * isn't bad practice if you really do need every column, people just seem to use it haphazardly and it's wasteful to select the entire row if you only need a couple of columns from it. In my experience with things like this you often don't need all the columns from one side of the join anyway.

Comment: If the table you're joining doesn't have too many columns I think it's not much of a pain to do it this way, just aliasing selected columns on one side. And if the table does have so many columns that it is a pain, that *might* be an indication another problem.

Comment: Very good points. Probably will go this aliasing route... because then I don't have to mess with my schema or prefix as a general rule. I could easily write a function like `makeSelect(string $table, array $columns, string $prefix)` and get back something like `table.col1 as pref_col1, table.col2 as pref_col2`. and then another to remove those prefixes in the resultset if I so wish.

Answer (score 0):

What I see as best practice is not to use same column names in different tables, that should be advised. Column name should be descriptive to its entity. In this case Pet.id should be Pet.pet_id and so on.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this approach. Prefixing my column names with the table name would... do what I need it to do, but is redundant, since I'm just repeating the table name as a prefix to the column name